# Given matrices $A,B, \det(A) = 2$ find $\det(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given matrices $A$,$B$, $\det(A) = 2$

**Find** $\det(B)$

$$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & 1 & b \\
        2 & 3a & 1 \\
        b & 1 & 2a \\
        \end{pmatrix},
\qquad B= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        3a & 3 + 3a & 0 &3(a+b)\\
        2a-2 & -a & 2 & 2a + 2b -3\\
        2b-2 & 2b-3a & 0 & 2b+4a-3\\
        2a-2 & -a & 0 & a+2b-3\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Well, I've tried doing some manipulations on $B$ and I wasn't success.
I believe first make det(B) like that:
$\det(B)= -2
        \begin{vmatrix}
        3a & 3 + 3a  &3(a+b)\\
        2b-2 & 2b-3a  & 2b+4a-3\\
        2a-2 & -a &  a+2b-3\\
        \end{vmatrix}
$

And then, I believe we need to take scalars $3$ of line 1, and somehow use determinant properties with "addition"(which makes $\det(B)$ into two determinants) which I don't know exactly how to implement. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your on the right track, but the 3x3 you have written there should be $\text{det} B$ and there should be a $-2$ multiplying the matrix on the right hand side.

Comment: @JohnMartin Still having some trouble with addition :(

Comment: You could also substract the first row from the last to get a simpler matrix with the same determinant.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I wasn't successful yet. Can you help please?

Comment: I think you may have a typo in your problem. I can manipulate $\det(B)$ to look close to, but not the same as, $\det(A)$, and I feel that they are probably supposed to be the same. In particular, I could get them to be the same if the lower right corner of $B$ was $2a+2b-3$.